# Simplifying this IF structure

Tags: javascript

Can you help me simplify this IF structure? This is javascript like node but something proprietary so ignore the db.execute stuff :)

```
if(!("Division" in Shipping))
    {
        var shipError = false;
        Shipping.Division = Billing.Division;
        if(!Shipping.Division)
        {
                if(Shipping.PostalCode)
            {
                Shipping.Division = Db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT Code from Location.Division D JOIN Location.PostalCode P ON DivisionId = D.ID AND PostalCode=?", Shipping.PostalCode);
                if(!Shipping.Division) shipError = true;
            }
            else
                shipError = true;
        }

        if(shipError){
                Errors.push({Code : "SHIPPINGDIVISION", Message : "Shipping State Required"});
                Shipping.Division = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to simplify it? Is it not working well, or is there any obscure bug, performance issue?

Comment: There is no simpler way to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using google closure?

It is a javascript optimizer. Try it out and see how it optimizes your code, if you like some of the optimizations you can use it in your code.

From the page.

> A JavaScript optimizer
>   The Closure Compiler compiles JavaScript into compact, high-performance code. The compiler removes dead code and rewrites and minimizes what's left so that it downloads and runs quickly. It also checks syntax, variable references, and types, and warns about common JavaScript pitfalls. These checks and optimizations help you write apps that are less buggy and easier to maintain. You can use the compiler with Closure Inspector, a Firebug extension that makes debugging the obfuscated code almost as easy as debugging the human-readable source.

The link [Google Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/)

Your code optimized.

```
if(!("Division" in Shipping)) {
  var shipError = !1;
  Shipping.Division = Billing.Division;
  if(!Shipping.Division) {
    Shipping.PostalCode ? (Shipping.Division = Db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT Code from    Location.Division D JOIN Location.PostalCode P ON DivisionId = D.ID AND PostalCode=?",  Shipping.PostalCode), Shipping.Division || (shipError = !0)) : shipError = !0
  }
  if(shipError) {
    Errors.push({Code:"SHIPPINGDIVISION", Message:"Shipping State Required"}),      Shipping.Division = ""
  }
}
;
```

Comment: Don't assume that automatically optimised code is as good as it gets. The answers given by @deceze and me are both just as short, yet both eliminate the `shipError` variable entirely and both are _much_ easier to read and therefore much more maintainable. The question was about "simplifying", but that line in the middle of the Google Closure version that starts `Shipping.PostalCode ?` is just silly - yes it does the same thing; doesn't make it _right_.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!Shipping.Division) {
    Shipping.Division = Billing.Division;
}
if (!Shipping.Division && Shipping.PostalCode) {
    Shipping.Division = Db.ExecuteScalar(...);
}
if (!Shipping.Division) {
    Errors.push({Code : "SHIPPINGDIVISION", Message : "Shipping State Required"});
}
```

Read this as:

- if not shipping division

  - try to take shipping division from billing division
- if not shipping division but postal code

  - try to get shipping division from postal code
- if still not shipping division

  - fail

Comment: That's good, but you also need to try to set `Shipping.Division` to `Billing.Division`.

Comment: `if (!Shipping.Division && !(Shipping.Division = Billing.Division) && Shipping.PostalCode) { ... }` would more accurately reflect the original algorithm...

Comment: @Tikhon I'm giving an example here, not writing production code.

Comment: @nnn **This example only includes the `if` logic, not the pre, post and in-between processing.** Clear enough? :)

Comment: But it doesn't include _all_ of the `if` logic, because (as Tikhon also pointed out) there is an additional `if` after setting `Shipping.Division` to `Billing.Division`. I believe if you were to replace your first `if` with the one from my previous comment then your answer would cover the entire thing including in-between processing.

Comment: @nnn Alright, due to popular demand I include the assignment of the billing division to the shipping division...

Comment: Ha! Thanks. I hate to nitpick again, but if you had instead used the (admittedly rather silly) if statement from my first comment that would take care of the assignment and the test such that the original question's outer if statement `if(!("Division" in Shipping))` would no longer be needed at all.

Comment: @nnn Maybe. I updated it including that logic, but whether this is the best way to go depends on the surrounding code I think.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `shipError` variable, you can just test `if(!Shipping.Division)` again at the end. This lets you eliminate the variable declaration (obviously), but also removes an `if` and an `else` that were only there to set `shipError = true`. Ends up like this:

```
if(!("Division" in Shipping)) {
   Shipping.Division = Billing.Division;
   if(!Shipping.Division) {
      if(Shipping.PostalCode) {
         Shipping.Division = Db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT statement here",
                                              Shipping.PostalCode);
      }    
   }
   if(!Shipping.Division){
      Errors.push({Code : "SHIPPINGDIVISION", Message : "Shipping State Required"});
      Shipping.Division = "";
   }
}
```